# How to reduce the height of a thumb in a switch?

Tags: android, android-switch

I am working on a Switch widget and I want to reduce the height of the thumb. By default the thumb's and the track's height are the same. But I want the thumb's height to be less than that of the track.

Thanks in advance for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the styles for the Switch widget are private, so you can change the drawable resources.

You can use the [Android Switch Backport library](https://github.com/BoD/android-switch-backport) and change the drawable resources to your needs.